# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: “” in android, server and port

Tags: android, numberformatexception

i'm new in Android. I have the following code:

```
    public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tcp_settings);

    Button buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConnect);
    buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        EditText server_ip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_server_ip);
        EditText port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_port);


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String serverAddr = server_ip.getText().toString();
            String serverPort = port.getText().toString();

            new connectTask().execute(serverAddr, serverPort);
        }
    });
}

class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Socket socket;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        int servport = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);

        try {
            socket = new Socket(params[0], servport);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return params[0] + " : " + params[1];
    }
}
}
```

I want to set a socket with server ip and port getting from EditTexts server_ip and port. In the connectTask I make a conversion from string to int in: int servport but i'm still getting error:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int "".
```

i have to make serverAddr to String because i have to put it in :

```
    new connectTask().execute(serverAddr, serverPort);
```

But then socket require port as Int so conversion is required.

Could You help me and tell what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: `params[1]==""` , `""` is not a valid `int` and hence when you do `Integer.parseInt(params[1])` , it throws `NumberFormatException`!!! Did you check what `port.getText().toString();` gives you ?

Comment: But why 'params[1]==""' ? I don't understand this... sorry i new it could be stupid qestion for You...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here within your code. You are passing in multiple parameters into a function that only receives one.  Here is the def of execute: `execute (Params... params)`

`new connectTask().execute(serverAddr, serverPort);`

Change line to this:

`new connectTask().execute(new String[]{serverAddr,serverPort});`

Although the documentation does not say it, it is wanting an array of the first template object being passed in **IF** you are passing in more than one parameter.

Comment: It helps, thank You very much. Could You tell me why I can't do it like it's in my code ?

Comment: @user2607507 I added a little more to my answer

Comment: In Android Documentation of AsynTask is an example, where:                  `new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);`. It's look like I'm able to sent multiple parameeters into `doInBackground`. Later:   `for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);`, so it's look like in `execute()` are elements of table.